Nginx, Load Balancers, CDN, API Gateway, is there an order of operations for these components?
I am new to the world of dev ops and I need some clarification on a few things. I have gone through several how-tos and they all have a different way of deploying web applications. Mainly, there's a lot of conflation between nginx, load balancers, cdn, reverse proxies, API Gateway, etc... I am wondering if there is a best practice way of doing things? For example, do load balancers go before my API gateway or after or both? What is the first point of contact after DNS resolution? Is it a load balancer or a CDN like Cloudflare? Is nginx a webserver that doubles as load balancer and a CDN?
